# Two keys in Map Collection?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, collections, key

If I run in any console the code below, we can see that there is a key (0,1,2 in the example shown below) and I can't understand why.

**It seems that we have two keys:** this autogenerated one and the key that you set manually (in the example. < key>: 1, < key>: 2, < key>: true)

I want to know why is it.

```
let mapTesting = new Map([
    [1, 'String'],
    [2, 123],
    [true, 'Testing']
]);
console.log(mapTesting)

//Output:
Map
  size: 3
  <entries>
    0: 1 → "String"
        <key>: 1
        <value>: "String"
    1: 2 → 123
        <key>: 2
        <value>: 123
    2: true → "Testing"
        <key>: true
        <value>: "Testing"
  __proto__: Object { … }
```

Comment: Aren't those just the indices of the iterable?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I really don' know, i am learning JS. This is my first week. :)

Comment: @PabloDeLuca `Map` can be iterated, and those are just the indices from the iteration. You should really learn about the more basic stuff before going into the new shiny ES6+ stuff.

Comment: Why if I print an object in the console has the same keys or identificators based on it properties? (0, 1, 2... ). And objects aren't iterables

Answer (score 0):

Because Map has a set of keys (like a hashmap) but can also be used as an iterator (forEach, entries). So the order of the keys are of some importance.

The [following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Description) description states:

> A Map object iterates its elements in **insertion order** — a for...of
>   loop returns an array of [key, value] for each iteration.

The 0,1,2,.. are to indicate the order (the order in which the key/values were added). Then the key and values are shown:

```
var mapTesting = new Map([
    ["one", 'String'],
    ["two", 123],
    ["three", 'Testing']
]);
mapTesting.set("another","value");
console.log(Array.from(mapTesting.keys()));
```

That shows an array that has the value "one" at index 0 because it was added first, then the value "two" at index 1 ...